# Populating comboboxes from reference table with multiple values

Tags: sql-server, combobox, vb6

I have a ref table saved in SQL-SERVER that has 3 sets of values. What I'm trying to do is populate 3 comboboxes with 3 different sets of values from that table.

```
Name     ID      Label      ORDER
Sports   1001    Soccer     1
SPorts   1002    Football   2
Sports   1003    Golf       3
Sports   1004    Basebal    4
Holidays 2001    Easter     1
Holidays 2002    Xmas       2
Holidays 2003    Thxgiving  3
```

and another set of values. I'm trying to populate one combobox with just sports, one with HOlidays and one with the other set. I'm able to populate them but with three function Functions, each one looks like this:

```
Set g_RS = New ADODB.Recordset
g_strSQL = "Select Name, ID, Label, Order from tblText_References where Name='Sports' Order By Order ASC"
Debug.Print g_strSQL
g_RS.Open g_strSQL, g_cnDatabase, adOpenStatic
cboSport.AddItem vbNullString
cboSport.ItemData(cboSport.NewIndex) = 0
While Not g_RS.EOF
    cboSport.AddItem g_RS("Label")
    cboSport.ItemData(cboSport.NewIndex) = g_RS("ID")
    g_RS.MoveNext
Wend
g_RS.Close
```

This works fine for sports, but i need a seperate function for each set of values in the ref table. Is there a way to combine it so that I call one function and it loads 3 comboboxes with the appropriate values. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Recordset's Filter property.  In your code above:

```
Set g_RS = New ADODB.Recordset
'REMOVE THE WHERE CLAUSE FROM THE SQL STATEMENT
g_strSQL = "Select Name, ID, Label, Order from tblText_References Order By Order ASC" 
g_RS.Open g_strSQL, g_cnDatabase, adOpenStatic
g_RS.Filter = "Name = 'Sport'" 'ADD THIS LINE
cboSport.AddItem vbNullString
cboSport.ItemData(cboSport.NewIndex) = 0
While Not g_RS.EOF
    cboSport.AddItem g_RS("Label")
    cboSport.ItemData(cboSport.NewIndex) = g_RS("ID")
    g_RS.MoveNext
Wend
```

The Filter property evaluates to a valid SQL WHERE clause.  So, then change the filter to "Name = 'Holiday'", populate your next ComboBox, and so on.

p.s. In some flavors of SQL you may need to put brackets around references to your Order field, so: [Order], since Order is a reserved keyword.